# The number of completions of a finite, consistent set of propositional logic formulas

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The following definitions and claims appear on p. 31 of Fred Kröger's *Temporal Logic of Programs* (Springer, 1987). The formulas under discussions are those of propositional temporal logic, but I think it is safe for the purpose of my question to assume regular propositional logic.

---

**Definition 1** A finite set $\mathcal{F} = \{A_1, \dots, A_n\}$ of formulas is called *inconsistent* if $\vdash\neg(A_1\wedge\dots\wedge A_n)$, otherwise it is called *consistent*.

**Definition 2** Let $F$ be  a formula. We define $\tau(F)$ to be the set of subformulas of $F$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of formulas, then we let $\tau(\mathcal{F})=\{A|A\in\tau(F), F\in\mathcal{F}\}$.

**Definition 3** A set $\mathcal{F}$ of formulas is called *complete* if for every formula $A\in\tau(\mathcal{F})$ either $A\in\mathcal{F}$ or $\neg A\in\mathcal{F}$ (but not both).

**Lemma 4** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a finite, consistent set of formulas. There is a finite, consistent and complete set $\mathcal{F}^*$ of formulas with $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{F}^*$.

**Definition 5** Let us call a set $\mathcal{F}^*$ according to Lemma 4 a *completion* of $\mathcal{F}$.

**Claim 6** In general, there may exist different completions of $\mathcal{F}$, but obviously only finitely many.

---

**Question**

Re claim 6: why are there only finitely many completions of $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Are you assuming the set of all propositional atoms to be finite?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku: No. The description of the logical language (on p. 9) states: "A denumerable set $\mathcal{V}$ of *atomic formulas*."

Comment: I think there may have been an omission in the textbook, and the containment in Lemma 4 should be $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{F}^*\subseteq\tau(\mathcal{F})$. This would explain why the number of completions is finite, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you allow countable many atoms then the statement is false.